# Есть ли в библиотеке jQuery методы, для вывода текста, которые не заменяют текст в <div> на информацию для печати, а добавляют ее после?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function getFile() {
      $.get("https://epamekids.github.io/README.md", function(data) {
        $("#text").innerHTML(data);
      });
    }
  </script>

<div id = "text">  
  <button onclick = "getFile()" id = "button">Get Information</button>  
</div>
```

Comment: @RazGalstyan этот метод также печатает информацию вместо кнопки, а мне нужно, чтобы в тот же __<div>__ информация добавлялась ниже кнопки, а не вместо нее.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/40apvm93/2/

Comment: @RazGalstyan, так твой код, как и код автора не работает же, потому что в jquery нет метода `innerHTML`, есть метод `html`

Comment: @Grundy извини там должно было быть `html`))).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для добавления в конец контейнера можно использовать метод [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

```js
function getFile() {
  $.get("https://epamekids.github.io/README.md", function(data) {
    $("#text").append(data);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="text">
  <button onclick="getFile()" id="button">Get Information</button>
</div>
```

Для добавления *после* выбранного элемента, а не внутрь его, можно воспользоваться методом [`after`](http://api.jquery.com/after/)

```js
function getFile() {
  $.get("https://epamekids.github.io/README.md", function(data) {
    $("#text").after(data);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="text">
  <button onclick="getFile()" id="button">Get Information</button>
</div>
```